# Buttons will not show on displayed fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-glide

I am currently creating a chat application for a project in Android Studio using Kotlin, Firebase Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore, and Glide, and I am following a few tutorials to do so. Everything was fine until I created a fragment to handle the user's account settings, such as name, bio, etc. The fragment appears to work and the edit text fields and profile picture can all be edited and interacted with, but neither of the buttons for saving and signing out seem to be displayed, and I can't figure out what the issue is exactly. As a result, I can't actually test the code until I can these buttons to be displayed. Any ideas?

This is what the fragment is supposed to look like, according to the layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qR0C.png

This is what the fragment looks like when the application is actually running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAgLG.png

This is what the fragment layout looks like in code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.MyAccountFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:hint="Your Name"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_profile_picture"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_bio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="275dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:hint="Your Bio"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_profile_picture"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.025" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:text="Save"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Sign Out"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.028"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the code for the fragment itself:

```
class MyAccountFragment : Fragment() {

    // Request code:
    private val RC_SELECT_IMAGE = 2
    // Variable for the selected image:
    private lateinit var selectedImageBytes: ByteArray
    // Picture change flag:
    private var pictureJustChanged = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false)

        view.apply {
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView_profile_picture).setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent().apply {
                    type = "image/*"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))
                }
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), RC_SELECT_IMAGE)
            }

            findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_save).setOnClickListener{
                if(::selectedImageBytes.isInitialized){
                    CloudStorageUtil.uploadProfilePicture(selectedImageBytes) { imagePath ->
                        CloudFirestoreUtil.updateCurrentUser(findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_name).text.toString(),
                            findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_bio).text.toString(),
                            imagePath)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    CloudFirestoreUtil.updateCurrentUser(findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_name).text.toString(),
                        findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_bio).text.toString(),
                        null)
                }
            }

            findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_sign_out).setOnClickListener {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                val intent = Intent(this@MyAccountFragment.context, LoginOrRegisterActivity::class.java)
                intent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?){
        if(requestCode == RC_SELECT_IMAGE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && data != null
            && data.data != null) {
            val selectedImagePath = data.data
            val selectedImageBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver, selectedImagePath)

            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            selectedImageBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream)
            selectedImageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray()

            GlideApp.with(this).load(selectedImageBytes).into(view?.findViewById(R.id.imageView_profile_picture))

            pictureJustChanged = true
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        CloudFirestoreUtil.getCurrentUser { user ->
            if(this@MyAccountFragment.isVisible){
                if (user != null) {
                    view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_name)?.setText(user.name)
                    view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_bio)?.setText(user.bio)
                    if(!pictureJustChanged && user.profilePicturePath != null){
                        GlideApp.with(this)
                            .load(CloudStorageUtil.pathToReference(user.profilePicturePath))
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24)
                            .into(view?.findViewById(R.id.imageView_profile_picture))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo That's just it: I don't know what in this code isn't working as I'd expect. I have no idea what is wrong with it, and I have absolutely no errors. All I know is that, for some reason, the two buttons that are supposed to be displayed when switching to the relevant fragment are not displayed regardless of any debugging or changes I try.